# Mongodb search field that is reference

Tags: mongodb, search, express, sails.js, waterline

New beginner of MongoDB here, I'm using sails.js(based on expressjs)/waterline(ORM)/MongoDB for this project. I have 2 collections, message and user. In any documents in message, there's this field called author that stores a reference/objectId of a user model:

```
module.exports = {
    autoCreatedAt: true,
    autoUpdatedAt: true,
    schema: true,
    tableName: 'message',
    attributes: {
        from: {
            model: 'user',
            required: true
        },
        to: {
            model: 'user',
            required: true
        },
        content: {
            type: 'string',
            maxLength: 288,
            required: true
        }
    }
};
```

My user collection goes like this:

```
module.exports = {
autoCreatedAt: true,
autoUpdatedAt: true,
schema: true,
tableName: 'user',
attributes: {
    email: {
        type: 'string',
        email: true,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: 'string',
        maxLength: 30
    },
    username: {
        type: 'string',
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        maxLength: 80
    },
    role: {     
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
   ......

},
```

};

Now I want to do a search query to all messages, given a search keyword, I want to show the paginated results of messages which the author's username and content of the message contains the keyword, how can I achieve that?

By the way, I know I can simply store username instead of user reference id in message documents, but says from Mongodb docs, objectId gives way better performance than string so...